# Power analysis for two groups

Tags: bayesian, sample-size, statistical-power

I am trying to claim that our sample size is large enough to justify a global difference between Group A and Group B using brain activity data at a given p of < 0.001 (uncorrected).

For each subject I have beta parameter estimates from an individual General Linear Model analysis for all brain areas during a specific task

What would be the best way to perform a power Analysis? Can Bayesian power analyis be used, as it provides complete distributions of credible values for group means and their differences (Kruschke, 2013, Bayesian estimation supersedes the t test. J. Exp. Psychol. Gen 142, 573–603 (2013)).

Essentially, I would like to claim something like that: group differences in brain activation could be identified with a (Bayesian) confidence interval of 95% using our sample size. On the other hand, I would like to argue/test that the lack of brain activation differences between Group A and B (after some computer-Training) is not due to a small sample size but a real effect.

Please consider that we get a different (i.e. subject-dependent) amount of activated regions in the brain. I don't know how a power analysis can deal with regional effects. In other words, although we have a parameter estimate for each subject for the regressor task, I know from data visualization that maps look different between subjects.

Comment: Why don't you just look at the confidence interval for the group difference, to say that if there is an effect, it is likely within +/- CI (note the caveats in interpreting frequentist CIs verbally).